# Kendo UI Angular window - prevent maximize

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, window, kendo-window

I'm using Kendo UI Window component for Angular and want to prevent users from maximizing the window. 
[Telerik Kendo UI Window component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/window/)

I was able to remove the Maximize-button, but a Dobuleclick on titlebar still maximizes the window (new class is set called 'k-window-maximized').

Anyone has solution for this? 
I tried with an event handler (dblclick) but it didn't work.

*** Solution ****

This worked for me:
set [resizable] to false

```
<kendo-window (close)="onClose()" [keepContent]="true"
  [resizable]="false" [draggable]="false" [width]="windowConfig?.width">
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Giannis I added the solution to my OP..

Comment: I want the user to be able to maximize the window resizing its dimensions manually.. So, setting resizable to false is not what I am actually looking for. I just want to remove the button (already done) and avoid double-click maximization..preventDefault() does not seem to work as well...

Comment: @Giannis how did you remove the maximize/minimize button from the window? I need to do this

Comment: @AliAlAmine Please ask a new question if this is the case.